Conditional Classname with Tailwind React Not Updating Style
selectedTopics.has(topic) is not returning True when it should in this case to display the conditional styling. When I replace selectedTopics.has(topic) with true, the conditional styling is applied so this is not where the issue is. The issue is that triviaTopics, a set is not returning true when selected.has(topic) should be true. Any tips for how something like this is achieved or why set.has() is behaving in this way. I have confirmed that triviaTopics have been added to the set selectedTopics at times and this issue still occurs.
const triviaTopics = [
  "Music of the 1960s",
  "Music of the 1970s",
...]

<div className="flex flex-wrap select-none">
              {triviaTopics?.map((topic, idx) => (
                <TopicCard
                  active={`${
                    selectedTopics.has(topic)
                      ? "!bg-right-blue !text-white"
                      : ""
                  }`}
                  key={idx}
                  topic={topic}
                  onClick={() => handleSelectTopic(topic)}
                />
              ))}
            </div>

export default function TopicCard({ topic, onClick, active }: TopicCardProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`bg-light-grey flex justify-center items-center w-80 h-20 m-4  text-text-black text-center align-middle rounded-lg  cursor-pointer transition-all hover:scale-105 ${active}`}
      onClick={() => onClick()}
    >
      <p>{topic}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

It seems like this is a rendering issue because when I select topics and then save the React project (triggering a rerender) the styles show up applied to the elements. For some reason the condition is not updating on state changes of the selected list being updated.
